# Is there any alternative to Tensorflow in Python which requires less storage space?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, optimization, deep-learning, voice-command

I've been trying to reduce the storage space needed to operate my company's wake-word detector such that it could fit into Raspberry Pi 3. The wake-word detector is using [Mycroft Precise](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-precise) to automate the detection processes.

After I dig into Mycroft Precise implementations, I found that the largest part of Mycroft Precise is actually not the main program, but just one dependency, which is tensorflow.

I find it really unacceptable when a dependency is actually 4 times bigger than the main program. Some alternatives like PyTorch aren't a better choice either.

Comment: It is not actually than uncommon in python for complex & advanced dependencies such as Machine Learning or Numpy to be larger than the main program that calls them _or even than the language itself_, e.g. on Windows Python 3.8 a bare install of python, _with built in libraries,_ is just under 12 MB but Numpy adds nearly 53 MB.

Comment: It is uncommon in IoT world.